# How to check search param using case statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have over 20 columns in my table. I have over 10 search fields in a C# dropdownlist. When the user searches, I pass the search fields from dropdownlist and search keywords from textbox. In SQL Server, I want to check what search field is selected like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Persons_SearchWithKeywords]
(
    @SearchField nvarchar(255), @Keywords nvarchar(255)
)
    SELECT * 
    FROM TB_Persons PER
    WHERE
        (CASE @SearchField 
            WHEN 'Name' THEN PER.Name = @Keywords
            WHEN 'Age' THEN PER.Age =  @Keywords
            WHEN 'PassportNo' THEN PER.PassportNo = @Keywords
            WHEN 'Township' THEN PER.Township = @Keywords
            WHEN 'Email' THEN PER.Email = @Keywords
            WHEN 'DateOfBirth' THEN PER.DOB = @Keywords
            WHEN ....
            WHEN ....
        )
```

Is it possible ?

When I execute it, I tried it and not work.
Please help.

Regards,
NNA

Comment: Not, this is **not** possible since `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that can return *one of several possible* values - but it **cannot** be used to control the flow of execution, or provide code fragments to your SQL statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=` and `OR`/`AND` instead of `CASE`:

```
SELECT * FROM TB_Persons PER
WHERE
      ( @SearchField = 'Name'       AND PER.Name       = @Keywords )
  OR  ( @SearchField = 'Age'        AND PER.Age        = @Keywords )
  OR  ( @SearchField = 'PassportNo' AND PER.PassportNo = @Keywords )
.....
```

Comment: Hello Tim... Thanks, I edited as your advise and it works.